# [C][Stat][Fileinfo] Why is st_mode defined as something not in structure, when I use the stat() call to return a structure?

Tags: c, struct, stat

I'm trying to use the `st_mode` from a returned `stat` struct, that I get from the `stat()` call following way;

```
        char *fn = "test.c"

        struct stat *buf = malloc(sizeof(stat));

        stat(fn,buf);

        if(S_ISREG(buf.st_mode))
        {
          printf("this file is a regular file..."); //if regular
        }
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
server1.c: In function ‘main’:
server1.c:223:32: error: request for member ‘st_mode’ in something not 
a structure or union
         if(S_ISREG(fileData.st_mode))
                            ^
```

Why do I get this compile error? I can't seem to find much info myself..

Comment: `buf` is a pointer to `struct stat` so you need `buf->st_mode`. Alternatively: declare `buf` as such: `struct stat buf;` and pass its address to `stat`: `stat(fn, &buf);`.

Comment: Wow thank you! Why is it like this? Say if I have a node struct with something like a `char data`. At first sight, I'd tell that `node->data` and `node.data` are the same. What's the difference in `struct stat`?

Comment: The dot `.` is used when you are dealing with a `struct` (or `union`) directly e.g when you have `struct something node;`. The in arrow `node->data` is short for `(*node).data` so `node` needs to be a *pointer* to a `struct` (or `union`) e.g. when you have `struct something * node;`.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

`buf` is not a `struct stat`. `buf` is a pointer to a `struct stat`, and pointers don't have `st_mode` fields. To get the `st_mode` field of the `struct stat` *that `buf` points to*, use `(*buf).st_mode`, or `buf->st_mode` for short.